# What's the best way to implement socket.io as a submodule within ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, express

I'm trying to build an ExpressJs based app using the submodule architecture suggested by tjholowaychuk.

I'd like to also have some realtime socket interaction, so I'm trying to integrate socket.io. I'm struggling to find the best way to do this as a sub app and allow both Express and socket.io listen together.

Comment: Did you read http://socket.io/#how-to-use ('Using with the Express (3)  web framework')?

Comment: I did indeed RTFM, but I'm having issues using it as a submodule.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Not sure what you mean by 'using it as a submodule'.

Comment: I'd like my socket.io logic to be away from the main app. I'd assumed I could do this using http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use as suggested by http://vimeo.com/56166857

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all `socket.io` related code in a separate file:

```
// socketio.js
var sio = require('socket.io');
module.exports = function(server) {
  var io = sio.listen(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection', ...);
  return io;
};

// app.js
var app    = require('express')(), 
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io     = require('./socketio')(server);
```